# PDO insert query not inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert some data using `PDO` like below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_category SET `category_title` = :cat_name  , `category_alias` = :category_alias , `category_status`= :cat_status, `category_parent_id` = $parent_id, "
            . "category_description =   '$cat_description'";
    $statement = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);

    $statement->bindParam(':cat_name', $cat_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':cat_status', $cat_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':category_alias', $category_alias, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindParam(':parent_id', $parent_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


if ($statement->execute()) {
        echo "executed"; exit;
        return $this->db->conn_id->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        echo "not executed"; exit;
    }
```

it always shows me "Not Executed", but when I run the query manually, it works fine

Comment: no its not a problem, we can use `set` in `insert` queryies, or you are saying `PDO` does not allows it??

Comment: Use `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` then, if you're not already doing so. It will outline your errors. You're obviously not checking for errors.

Comment: already tried that, it does not show any thing

Comment: $parent_id should be :parent_id

Comment: MySQL syntaxes are really weird.

Comment: @Mihai Spotted an error. +1

Comment: You have 3 binds in your INSERT, then 4 `bindParam`'s. That's the major issue here.

Comment: By the way, once this executes `echo "executed"; exit;` - it stops there and will not execute `return $this->db->conn_id->lastInsertId();`. So, remove the `exit;`

Comment: but it is not entering in `if` condition, always goes in `else`

Comment: Well, that's kind of comforting. You'll need to remove it any which way. I suggest you cut down your query to a single bind. If it works, put the 2nd one in... and keep going till it hits a snag.

Comment: yeah I tried that and its working with 3 binds and 2 by reference insertion :)

Comment: Ok, so fix the one that is preventing it, what's hard about that? You don't need us. Only you know what's in your DB, and its schema. This is a debugging issue.

Comment: yeah, but its weird, don't know why its not binding the other parameters

Comment: Are you sure `$parent_id` is an `INT`? Plus, which one exactly is not binding? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing bind and strings.

Bind

```
$parent_id
$cat_description
```

You have typos my friend. Clean up your code.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_category SET `category_title` = :cat_name  , `category_alias` =     :category_alias , `category_status`= :cat_status, `category_parent_id` = :parent_id, category_description =   :cat_description";
```

Comment: for this, i am facign the following problem :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069715/pdo-parameter-is-not-binding